# php shopping cart, stack quantities

Tags: php

I am making a php shopping cart where you add products and after that, the order details like name, quantity, and price of the product are displayed in the bottom of the page along with the total of the order. I want to make it so that when you add a product that has already been added to the cart, it stacks the quantities. For exampe if you have a product like red cup with the price of 5$ and quantity of 1 and after that you add it to the cart again with the quantity of 2, the order details section shows red cup, quantity of 3 with the price 15$.I am using a session vriable to store the products of the cart and their details.

Here is the block of code that creates the session, I know I have to write something in that else statement but I don't know how to access the price of the element in the cart:

```
<?php
//session_unset();
//session_destroy();
if(isset($_POST["addtocart"])) {
    //var_dump($_SESSION["cart"]);
    $_SESSION["cos"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart"]);
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {
        $item_array_id=array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"id");
        $item_array_cant=array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"cantitate");

        if(!in_array($_POST["id"],$item_array_id)) {
            $count=count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array=array(
                             'id'  => $_POST["id"],
                             'name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                             'price'       => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                             'quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
                    );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count]=$item_array;
        }
           **else** 
           {


           }

    } else {
        $item_array=array( 
                         'id'  => $_POST["id"],
                         'name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                         'price'       => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                         'quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
            );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0]=$item_array;
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action']=="delete"){
        for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION["cart"]);$i++) {
            if($i==$_GET['id']) {
                unset($_SESSION["cart"][$i]);
            }
        }
        $_SESSION["cart"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart"]);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ___Small Point___ You use `$_SESSION["cart"]` before you test for its existance in this line`if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]))` If the existance needs checking you really need to do things in a logical order there

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the id as the key of the cart array, finding a duplicate and then adding to the price would be nice and easy.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["addtocart"])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart"])) {

        $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];     // just make addressing the cart easier

        if(!isset($cart[$_POST['id']]) ) {
            $cart[$_POST['id']] = ['id'  => $_POST["id"],
                                   'name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                                   'price'       => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                                   'quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
                                   ];
        } else {
            // get current quantity from cart and add new quantity
            $q = $cart[$_POST['id']]['quantity'] + $_POST["quantity"];
            $cart[$_POST['id']]['quantity'] = $q;
            $cart[$_POST['id']]['price'] = $q * $_POST["hidden_price"];
        }

    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']] = ['id'  => $_POST["id"],
                                           'name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                                           'price'       => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                                           'quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
                                           ];
    }
}
```